# Comparing Supervisor's Salaries

Tags: sql, subquery, self-join

I'm trying to display employees who make at least 25% of what their supervisor makes. So far I have a subquery code that can display the supervisors themselves, but I'm not sure how to "grab" the supervisor salaries:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT firstname + ' ' + lastname        AS Employee, 
                         id, 
                         jobtitle                          AS [Job Title], 
                         Str(Round(salary / 12, 2), 12, 2) AS [Monthly Salary] 
FROM   employeetable 
WHERE  ( id IN (SELECT supervisor 
                 FROM   employeetable 
                 WHERE  ( supervisor IS NOT NULL )) ) 
ORDER  BY lastname, 
          firstname
```

Comment: Is the supervisor field the employeeid of the supervisor or a yes/no field?

Comment: Which database system and which version?

Comment: SQL 2012 and the supervisor field contains the ID of the supervisor, but the supervisors are listed as normal employees in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

-- First, find employees and supervisors

```
select emp.id,emp.Salary,Sup.SuperVisor,Sup.Salary
from employeetable emp
join employeetable Sup on emp.supervisor=Sup.id
```

Now add the where clause

```
where emp.Salary >= .25 * Sup.Salary
```

to eliminate people who are supervisors

```
and emp.id not in (select distinct supervisor from employeetable)
```

Comment: Sure hope his table has those fields.

Comment: My problem is that the supervisors are listed as normal employees on the same table. The only way to tell that they are supervisors is that their ID is listed under the supervisor variable of other employees.

Comment: So are you saying, if a person is a supervisor, you do not want to compare them with their supervisor as well?